# Strange happenings with NSDateFormatter

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I am using a UIPickerView to display hours to choose from, which wants to go from 00:00 through to 23:00, however I am obviously doing something wrong as I am getting 11:58 through to 10:58. Here is what I am doing:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components: NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit
                                                   fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [dateComponents setHour:row];
    [dateComponents setMinute:0];
    [dateComponents setSecond:0];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents]];
}
```

Any help would be much appreciate.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Have you tried settings a different time zone? like `[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]`

Comment: @Eugene - I have tried your suggestion, however it has had no effect. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Logs the dates as NSDate, then logs the dates as NSString. Anyways, your NSDateFormatter should have a local/timeZone.

Comment: @Larme Thank you, setting a time zone for the NSDateFormatter has fixed my problem.

Comment: If you are going to use an NSDateFormatter, at a minimum you should initialize it (as well as the NSCalendar) once outside of your delegate method instead of creating it again and again for every row in your picker view.

Comment: @MattLong Very good point, I missed that one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Larme gave me the answer required (setting a time zone for the NSDateFormatter).

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any reason to use a date formatter inside your picker delegate method. The number of hours and minutes in a day are fixed. Why not just present the user with a two column picker providing hours in one and minutes in the other.

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", row];
}
```

Here is what your picker data source methods would look like.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    // Two picker columns, one for hours, one for minutes
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (component) {
        case 0:
            return 24;
        case 1:
            return 60:
    }
}
```

Then, when your user is done picking, build your date based on what they chose.

```
- (IBAction)didTapDonePickingButton:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger hour = [_pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSInteger minute = [_pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1];

    // Build out your date here...
}
```

**Better Yet**, did you know you can just use a UIDatePicker and set its mode to "Time" in interface builder.

[image]

This will give you just hours and minutes. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Matt - If you notice in my question I want to display hours only (00:00 - 23:00), and you cannot do this using a UIDatePicker (unless I am mistaken). Also, I am using the NSDateFormatter to display AM or PM next to the hours.

Comment: If you are using 24 hour time (00:00 - 23:00), why would you need AM/PM?

Comment: Because that is what the client wants.

Comment: Well, there's that. ;-)